# Certain elements in tcl array not accessable (i.e. "no such element in array")

Tags: arrays, tcl, global

I have declared an array, of which I can access all of the elements through a loop but hen I try to directly access some elements, they do not exist.

I have tried accessing the array through CUI, writing scripts to do so, both in a loop, directly, and by making the key a variable; the behavior is very bizzare.

I have my array tileDirectory declared from before hand and when I enter in the CUI

> > foreach {a b} [array get tileDirectory] {puts $a}
> >
> > …
> >
> > xu/iq/grf/reg23DataReg/[0]
> >
> > su/pipe/dcacheTag/dcPLRUEntry[31].dcPLRUEntryXReg/[0]
> >
> > xu/cq/cq00/cqStatusReg/[0]
> >
> > su/busReq/memIntfc/memReqStDataReg/[96]_nocgc

However if I do:

> > puts $tileDirectory(su/pipe/dcacheTag/dcPLRUEntry[31].dcPLRUEntryXReg/[0])
> >
> > can't read "tileDirectory(su/pipe/dcacheTag/dcPLRUEntry[31].dcPLRUEntryXReg/[0])": no such element in array

I would except that I could read the element of the array, as a note the other elements I can read out just fine, and for the sake of pattern, it tends to be the names which have "." in them that give me trouble

Comment: That's strange. I would have expected the error to be: invalid command name "31"

Comment: What if you do: `set key {su/pipe/dcacheTag/dcPLRUEntry[31].dcPLRUEntryXReg/[0]}; puts $tileDirectory($key)` ?

Comment: @glenn jackman: that still gives me “no such element in array”, very bizzare

Comment: What happens when you just `puts [list [array get tileDirectory]]` -- do you see any extra spaces?

Comment: @glennjackman that works fine, everything prints out, even the entry that was giving me the error, if in my original loop I to puts $tileDirectory($a) instead of puts $a, even that works, even though its calling the same array key

Comment: What is the source for the keys? Are they being read from a file? Do they contain carriage returns? Do they contain unicode characters that only look like ascii characters? As the question currently exists, it is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have your array defined in multiple places (or in different namespaces) such as the sample program below.  For the following program to work, the `global td` statement must be uncommented.

```
proc myproc { } {
  # global td
  set td(abc) 123

  puts $td(def)
}

set td(def) 456
puts $td(def)
myproc
```

Comment: my array is defined globally, and that wouldn't make sense bc then how come my array access work for everything else perfectly fine, it only seems to be giving me trouble with keys that contain a period (".") in their variable.